# ORACLE how to use RANK function

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

Good Morning,

I can not get the result what I want right now.

for example my code is

```
select 
    a.donor_id AS ID
  , a.date_of_record
  , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a.donor_id,a.date_of_record  ORDER BY date_of_record) r_nk
from table a
```

The result is

```
ID ----------------Date_of_record-----r_nk
012                12/14/2017         1
012                12/20/2017         1
012                12/20/2017         1
```

however I would like to show like this

```
 ID ----------------Date_of_record-----r_nk
    012                12/14/2017         1
    012                12/20/2017         1
    012                12/20/2017         2
```

I am not sure why the code above is not working,

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: how do you know which row with 12/20/2017 should come first? Technically there is a tie so they are both rank 1.

Comment: Dear @SQLChao, shoot, You are right!!!!! I should use row_number!!!!

Comment: @supercooldjkazu - you could still use `rank()`, but only if you have another column you can use to break the tie. That's true with `row_number()` too really - that will work without an explicit tie break, but the result will be indeterminate. (Which doesn't really matter with just those three columns in the result set, but then the ranking isn't telling you much anyway...)

Comment: It never, ever, makes sense to order by a column (or expression, more generally) that is also included in `partition by` - for **any** analytic function. In a given partition, that expression will be constant, so it will not order *the partition* in any way. Think about this first, and figure out what you really need the query to do, before you try any other approaches.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you could use `ROW_NUMBER()` so each row gets a unique value.

```
select 
    a.donor_id AS ID
  , a.date_of_record
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.donor_id,a.date_of_record  ORDER BY date_of_record) r_nk
from table a
```

Comment: Same mistake as the OP: It never, ever makes sense to order by a column that is already included in `PARTITION BY`. As long as you do that, the partition is not ordered in any way - the value of that column is CONSTANT in the partition.